# Front-end editing with custom fields?

Tags: custom-field, users, front-end

I use the custom field plugin http://www.advancedcustomfields.com

Is it possible to create and edit custom posts via the front end? I'd need to be able to see all the custom fields and allow those to be edited as well. Users should only be allowed to edit their own posts if they are logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do with
[**wp insert post**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) and 
[**wp update post**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post)

Answer (score 0):

You can obviously show custom fields on front end but you may have to do it yourself. Here is a tutorial that explains how to add custom field on the front end

http://voodoopress.com/add-a-meta-box-to-use-custom-fields-on-front-end-post-form/

if you've understood how it works, you will get able to add all fields (or even filtered fields). you can retrieve all custom fields related to a post using the following function:

```
get_post_custom($post_id)
```

you will get an array of fields which you can iterate over to create form fields in the metabox.

i've given you some hints which you can use as guide to implement yourself. i'm sorry as it is not possible to provide complete solution